# Return specific value in range

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say there are two columns: A and B each with five rows.  Column A has value P03675 in all five rows and Column B has TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE in rows, just  like this:

```
A         B
P03675  TRUE
P03675  TRUE
P03675  FALSE
P03675  FALSE
P03675  TRUE
```

Column A contains the same value but I need a formula which would look for P03675 and return a result if Column B is FALSE.

Comment: What result should it return? Would this example return True (it does exist) or 3(the third row is the first match) or 2 (there are two matches)?

Comment: It would return "2 (there are two matches)".  I would however appreciate solutions for all three that you've mentioned, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number that satisfy both conditions (A=P03675 and B = FALSE) you can use `COUNTIFS`.

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"=p03675",B1:B5,"=FALSE") //returns 2
```

If you just want a TRUE/FALSE if any exist use the above with > 0.

To get the position of the first match, you'll have to give me a minute or two.